# What is the correct way to combine these SPF records?

Tags: dns, spf

Having done a recent MX check I have noticed that our domain has multiple SPF records. I was just wondering if anyone knew the correct way to combine the follow?

v=spf1 +a +mx ~all
v=spf1 include:_spf.google.com ~all

I would assume it is just

v=spf1 +a +mx include:_spf.google.com ~all

Could anyone verify if this is in fact correct?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's correct, yes. You can use a tool like this one to help you test the SPF record before you update your DNS settings to ensure it's syntactically correct: http://www.kitterman.com/spf/validate.html